# How to set cell style using OpenOffice::OODoc?

Tags: perl, odf

How to apply a style to cell using OpenOffice::OODoc module in Perl?

I tried:

```
my $container = odfContainer("report1.ods", create => 'spreadsheet');

my $doc = odfDocument (
                       container => $container,
                       part      => 'content'
                      );

# Styles
my $styles = odfDocument (
                       container => $container,
                       part      => 'styles'
                      );

$styles->createStyle ('TTT',
        family       => 'cell',
        display-name => 'Table Headers',
        properties   => {
            'fo:font-weight' => 'bold',
            'fo:color'       => '#ffffff',
        }
);

{
    for (my $x = 0; $x < $X; $x++) {
        $doc->columnStyle ($sheet, $x, "TTT"); # does not work
        for (my $y = 0; $y < $Y; $y++) {
            my $cell = $doc->getTableCell ($sheet, $y, $x);
            $doc->cellValueType ($cell, $headers->[$x][1]);
            $doc->updateCell ($cell, $data->[$y][$x]);
            $doc->setStyle ($cell, 'TTT'); # does not work
            $doc->cellStyle ($cell, 'TTT'); # does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [style](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/OpenOffice::OODoc::Document#style%28object_%5b,_style%5d%29):

> `style(object [, style])`
>
> Returns the style name of a text or graphics object. If the first
>       argument is a "master page" (see OODoc::Styles), it even returns the
>       associated "page layout".
>
> Replaces the object's style if a style name is given as the second
>       argument.

Comment: When I try `$doc->style ($cell, 'TTT');` I get "[OpenOffice::OODoc::Document::style] Missing object" warning message.

Comment: Ok, It works. `cellStyle` works too. There was problem with `createStyle` method.